# c++ .cpp file null encode in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, visual-studio-2015

I am making a code in visual studio MFC.

When I doing remote debug in visual studio to my vmware, I see the blue screen( CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED). and reboot system.

then, i open the visual studio again.
my .cpp code is null encoded....
Only one class in All solution.

What did it?
.cpp's size is same before. but content is all null...

I use Visual Studio 2015

[image]

Comment: Possibly caused by the cache not being written to the disk before the system died.  If you have some form of source code control, you should be able to get the code back prior to the mods.  If you haven't got source code control and haven't taken a backup, you're out of luck.

Comment: you could dump your disc and search for file contents .. but this is very hard as its a text file

Comment: Thanks all. you says it is caused system down. ok.. I make code again....